# Bolding values in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

I would like to bold values in a table on Power bi's canvas. Is there a way to bold a value in Power bi by using its wizards rather than programming?
Tried to search for an answer, but didn't succeed finding it.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the text font style in Segoe UI (Bold) for workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this feature isn't currently available in Power BI.
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/bold-value-in-table-visualization/td-p/185890

Here is a community idea you can vote on if you want this implemented:
https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/11602134-additional-font-formatting-bold-italic-underlin

One alternative is to change the color of values, which you can do by selecting your table, going to the Format tab on the right, and find the Conditional Formatting section. (The Field formatting does not let you specify which rows to format, nor does it have any text markup besides color). In the Conditional Formatting section you can play around with the Font Color options by toggling it on and selecting values and colors.

[image: Font color scales]

Unfortunately this isn't exactly what you were looking for but this is probably the best way to distinguish values in a Power BI table currently.

Comment: I just checked my calendar to make sure it's 2019 outside.   Microsoft sells Report BI as an enterprise tool and there is no way to bold a cell ?

Comment: @David It's almost 2024 and there's still no way of doing it without jumping through a thousand hoops to get there. It's just the way of Microsoft, I've come to realize. 

The standard answer from support is always: "There's currently no way of doing this just because there is no way to do this, because we won't allow it, but you can vote for the feature to be added lmao :)"